# Rpy2: set a R formulat from python

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am little confused by R syntax formula

I created the following python function with Rpy2:

```
objects.r('''

  project_var <- function(grid,points) {
      coordinates(points) = ~X + Y
      gridded(grid) = ~X+Y
      grid = idw(Z~1, points,grid)
      grid <- as.data.frame(grid)
      return(grid)
   }
''')
```

Then I import it

```
project_var = robjects.globalenv['project_var']
```

Then  I call it:

```
test = project_var(model,points_top)
```

And it works as expected!

I would like to'Z' to be set by an argument of my function, something like this:

```
      project_var <- function(grid,points,feature_name) {
...
          grid = idw(feature_name~1, points,grid)
```

My Problem :

```
idw(feature_name~1, points,grid)
```

I do not really understand this line and what is really feature name (because it is not a string nor known variable at this point, but the name of a column as a formula).

for info idw comes from gstat library... and I do not know R... 
here is the doc:

> idw.locations(formula, locations, data, newdata, nmax = Inf, nmin = 0,
>   omax = 0, maxdist = Inf, block, na.action = na.pass, idp = 2.0,
>   debug.level = 1)
>   https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gstat/gstat.pdf

So what should I put for feature_name in the python side ? or how to build it in R so it would transform the string feature_name into something that would work ?
Any help would be appreciate.

Thank you for reading so far.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not really understand this line and what is really feature name (because it is not a string nor known variable at this point, but the name of a column).

R differs from Python as expressions in a function call (here `idw(Z~1, points,grid)`) will only be evaluated within the function, and the unevaluated expression itself is available to the code in the body of the function.

In addition to that, `Z~1` is itself a special thing: it is an R formula. You could write `fml <- Z ~ 1` in R and the object `fml` will be a "formula". The constructor for the formula is somewhat hidden as `<something> ~ <something>` is considered a language construct in R, but in fact you have something like `build_formula(<left_side_expression>, <right_side_expression>)`. You can try in R `fml <- get("~")(Z, 1)` and see that this is exactly that happening.

Comment: Thank you for your help. And I found the answer to this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

okay, just need to use as.formula to convert a string to a formula :-)

```
idw(as.formula(feature_name), points,grid)
```